# Output from bash command not storing in array

Tags: arrays, perl

my below code is very simple... all im doing is grepping a file using an IP address REGEX, and any IP addresses that are found that match my REGEX, I want to store them in @array2.

i know my REGEX works, because ive tested it on a linux command line and it works exactly how I want, but when its integrated into the script, it just returns blank. there should be 700 IP's stored in the array.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @array2 = `grep -Eo "\"\b[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\"" test1.txt`;
print @array2;
```

Comment: What output do you get from printing @array2?

Comment: I would say newbies don't mix perl and shell as it doesn't work for them, and experienced ones simply know better.

Answer (score 3):

Backticks ``` `` ``` behave like a double quoted string by default.

Therefore you need to escape your backslashes:

```
my @array2 = `grep -Eo "\\"\\b[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\"" test1.txt`;
```

Alternatively, you can use a single quoted version of [`qx`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/qx.html) to avoid any interpolation:

```
my @array2 = qx'grep -Eo "\"\b[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\"" test1.txt';
```

However, the method I'd recommend is to not shell out at all, but instead do this logic in perl:

```
my @array2 = do {
    open my $fh, '<', 'test1.txt' or die "Can't open file: $!";
    grep /\b[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\b/, <$fh>;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I really wouldn't mix bash and perl. It's just asking for pain. Perl can do it all natively.

Something like:

```
open (my $input_fh, "<", "test.txt" ) or die $!;
my @results = grep ( /\b[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}/, <$input_fh> );
```

This does however, require slurping the file into memory, which isn't optimal - I'd generally use a `while` loop, instead.

Answer (score 1):

The text inside the backticks undergoes double-quotish substitution. You will need to double your backslashes.

Running `grep` from inside Perl is dubious, anyway; just slurp in the text file and use Perl to find the matches.

Comment: Perl does have a `grep` builtin, which'll do the trick. I'd tend to use a `while` loop instead though, because it's less memory expensive.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to retrieve the output from an external command is to use open():

```
open(FH, 'grep -Eo \"\b[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\" test1.txt'."|")  
my @array2=<FH>;
close (FH);
```

..though I think Sobrique's idea is the best answer here.